# Identifying symbol similar to opamp

Tags: identification, symbol

What is this symbol and what it does? It looks like the Op-Amp on the left, but I don't get what that half square wave is doing on it.

[image]

This diagram was obtained from this paper:

```
@article{CamuasMesa2019,
  title = {Neuromorphic Spiking Neural Networks and Their Memristor-CMOS Hardware Implementations},
  volume = {12},
  ISSN = {1996-1944},
  url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.3390/ma12172745},
  DOI = {10.3390/ma12172745},
  number = {17},
  journal = {Materials},
  publisher = {MDPI AG},
  author = {Camuñas-Mesa,  Luis and Linares-Barranco,  Bernabé and Serrano-Gotarredona,  Teresa},
  year = {2019},
  month = aug,
  pages = {2745}
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's a comparator.

When the input exceeds the reference voltage the output switches high and vice versa.

Comment: Understood, is there a particular name for that component?

Comment: @ÍcaroLorran It's called a comparator.

Comment: @ÍcaroLorran "Comparator" is its name.

Comment: Thanks, does it have any relation with the Schmitt Trigger?

Comment: @ÍcaroLorran In the sense that a schmitt trigger is just a comparator with hysteresis, which is achieved by making the threshold voltage different for low-to-high and high-to-low transitions.

Comment: A comparator with hysteresis, or schmitt trigger, is generally shown with a hysteresis loop graphic inside the triangle, not just a digital step. Visually very similar; they're just two lines apart!